# how to access HUE from jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, hive, hue

I work on the HUE in my company. Lately we are trying to execute Python script in hive editor. Can you help us as to how to run a python script on HUE hive interface.

Comment: hive doesn't work with python but with HQL. what do you want to do exactly ?